# Gameobject won't instantiate children of prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a breakable platform that I want to re spawn after 5 seconds of it being broken. It breaks perfectly and re-spawns. However none of the children of the prefab it's re-spawning from spawn. The way I have the platform set up is there's a parent that holds the script, trigger box collider and audios source. And then there's 4 children that are the graphics and also they brake off from the parent and a rigid body turns on once it's been stepped on. Can any one help?

```js
#pragma strict

var Platform : GameObject;
var child1 : GameObject;
var child2 : GameObject;
var child3 : GameObject;
var child4 : GameObject;
var audio2 : AudioSource;
private var hasPlayed = false;

function Start (){
    child1.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
    child2.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
    child3.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
    child4.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
}

function OnTriggerEnter2D(Other : Collider2D){

    if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        child1.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
        child2.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
        child3.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
        child4.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
        transform.DetachChildren();
        renderer.enabled = false;
        audio.Play();
        Respawn();
     }
 }

function Respawn(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(5);
    audio2.Play();
    var PlatformClone = Instantiate(Platform, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Does the prefab contain all the children in the `project` view?

Comment: Why you destroy your gameObject?

Comment: @maZZZU Yes, they're parented in the project view.

Comment: @Barış Çırıka  Because then there will be to breakable platforms when there only needs to be one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but I think your problem come from [`transform.DetachChildren()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.DetachChildren.html).Using this command will destroy the hierarchy.If you are doing it on the instantiated `GameObject`, it would work.

But if you are doing it on the prefab itself, your `GameObject` would have no child for the rest of the runtime.

And you would have probably more chance to find the answers to your issues [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/).

Comment: No, i think it's just detaching the children on the gameobject

Comment: If your prefab is tagged as `Player`, children attach to your prefab would get detach, you should just verify, this could just a little thing like that.